# Why the default properties are not working when creating spreadsheet with Google Sheets API v4?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to set the default properties for the spreadsheet, which I create by Google Sheets API.
I did everything according to the documentation for the API, but the newly created spreadsheet doesn't have these default values.
The only things it has are the titles of the spreadsheet and the sheet, the rowCount and columnCount. NO horizontalAlignment, no verticalAlignment, no wrap, no font, no font size, no borders.

Here are the default properties which I am trying to set.

```
    # Spreadsheet body
    sheet_body = {
        'properties': {
            'title': 'Test_Spreadsheet',
            'defaultFormat': {
                'horizontalAlignment': 'CENTER',
                'verticalAlignment': 'MIDDLE',
                'wrapStrategy': 'WRAP',
                'textFormat': {
                    'fontFamily': 'calibri',
                    'fontSize': 14,
                    'bold': True
                },
                'borders': {
                    'top': {'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1},
                    'right': {'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1},
                    'bottom': {'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1},
                    'left': {'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1}
                }
            }
        },
        'sheets': [ {
            'properties': {
                'title': 'Total',
                'gridProperties': {
                    'rowCount': 5,
                    'columnCount': 3
                }
            }
        } ]
    }

    # Create spreadsheet
    sheet = service.spreadsheets().create(body=sheet_body).execute()
```

Why they are not working???? Please, help.

Thanks

I tried different values without success.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `Why they are not working????`?

Comment: Yes. What details you what to know?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `Why they are not working????`. So, I asked about the detail of your current issue. For example, 1. What is your error message? 2. What is your current issue?

Comment: There is no errors, but the result of this script is the new spreadsheet on the google drive with the name Test_spreadsheet, with 1 sheet called Total which has 5 rows and 3 columns. That's it. No borders, no default font which I tried to set and so on. That's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you wanted to set `defaultFormat`. In the current stage, the official document says `This field is read-only.` about `defaultFormat`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SpreadsheetProperties) I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `That's it. No borders, no default font which I tried to set and so on.`.

Comment: Now, I found the related thread with your question. I think that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60547769

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I flagged it as the duplicated question of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60547769